# Trace every steps in Python Script

Tags: python, trace

I am new to Python scripting and i have one big script for an automation. I am trying to understand how that script is tracing the supplied data. i am not able to trace each and every steps how the flow and what will be value at each step. Is there any way that I can trace each step and what will be the value at that step/after completing that step. Can any one please help me here?

Comment: What do you mean by "tracing the supplied data"? Have you tried using break points?

Comment: I mean, I will supply the data to python, how that data is getting changed in each step in python. Can I trace that? How break points will solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your program line-by-line, great tools exist that are called debuggers. You should use python debugger (pdb).

If you use PyCharm, a graphical interface is provided for it and show the variable contents[image: PyCharm debugger in action]

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a great tool. I have one question. I have an ansible playbook which will internally call the python script (which I mentioned above) and gets executed and return to ansible playbook again. While calling python, it will pass the values and that values will be used in python script. Can I trace the python alone while ansible playbook supplying the values? May be I am complicating the things here. Please don't mind

Comment: @SridharAdurthi I honestly don't know. Maybe you can print the values from your plybook and run your script in the debugger with these values

Comment: Thank you. good one. I have started collecting the values from Ansible and trying to recreate in python using pycharm. Helps a lot. Thanks much.